# Retrive record from db and display in listview and pass value on click event to next activity

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite

i am developing app in which i want to parse xml file and store it in db and retrieve particular record from table and display it in list view, and when i will click on it, pass that value to next activity through intent. i have tried it. when i will install that .apk of application it works fine, but when i came back to list view activity and click on any value it gives error as "forse close" and application is terminated. and in log cat it gives error as given below.

it's fetching records from db and displaying in list view every time perfectly. am getting error onclick event and that also when i am come back to list view again.

please help me to solve problem...
thank you in advance...!

> **Logcat error**

```
> *03-22 22:07:51.681: E/AndroidRuntime(336): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 22:07:51.681: E/AndroidRuntime(336): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:     Invalid index 1, size is 0
03-22 22:07:51.681: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
03-22 22:07:51.681: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
03-22 22:07:51.681: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at com.dod.test.List_of_Consumer$1.onItemClick(List_of_Consumer.java:130)
03-22 22:07:51.681: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
03-22 22:07:51.681: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
03-22 22:07:51.681: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
03-22 22:07:51.681: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-22 22:07:51.681: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-22 22:07:51.681: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-22 22:07:51.681: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-22 22:07:51.681: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 22:07:51.681: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-22 22:07:51.681: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-22 22:07:51.681: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-22 22:07:51.681: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)*
```

**List_of_Consumer**  // *first activity where i am retrieving reords from db and display in listview.*

```
package com.dod.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class List_of_Consumer extends Activity {
Button back;
Intent i;
TextView txt_xml;
String consumer_id,meter,or,current,s;
ListView lv;
ArrayList<String> cid;
ArrayList<String> a;
InputStream is;
DB_Adapter database;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_of_consumer);
    back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnback);
    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
    database = new DB_Adapter(getApplicationContext(), "EBS", null, 1);

    try
    {

        a = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(database.count())
        {
            getxmldata();
        }else
        {
            File xml = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "t21.xml");
            is = new FileInputStream(xml);
            //is = new FileInputStream("/data/data/com.dod.test/t21.xml");
            InputStreamReader isr= new InputStreamReader(is);



                XmlPullParserFactory xf=XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                XmlPullParser xp=xf.newPullParser();
                xp.setInput(isr);
                int event=xp.getEventType();

                while(event!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
                {
                    if(event==XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
                    {
                        current=xp.getName();
                    }
                    else if(event==XmlPullParser.TEXT)
                    {
                        if(current.equals("consumerid"))
                        {

                            a.add(xp.getText());    

                            consumer_id=xp.getText();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), consumer_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                        else if(current.equals("meter"))
                        {
                            meter=xp.getText();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), meter, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else if(current.equals("or"))
                        {
                            or=xp.getText();
                            database.addConsumer(consumer_id, meter,or);
                            database.close();
                        }

                    }               

                    event=xp.next();

                    }
                    getxmldata();
        }





            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    String st=a.get(arg2);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Consumer:="+st, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Reading_Detail.class);
                    i.putExtra("key", st);
                    startActivity(i);
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    /*back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Home.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });*/

}

public void getxmldata()
{
    cid=database.get_consumer_id();
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row,R.id.txt,cid);
    lv.setAdapter(aa);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_of_consumer, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

**DB_Adapter** // *database file*

```
package com.dod.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DB_Adapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public SQLiteDatabase db;
String s2,s3;
public static final String KEY_NAME = "USERNAME";
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "PASSWORD";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "LOGIN";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE1 = "CONSUMER";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE2 = "CONSUMER_XML";
public DB_Adapter(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
        int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    arg0.execSQL("CREATE TABLE LOGIN(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            "USERNAME TEXT NOT NULL," +
            "PASSWORD TEXT NOT NULL)");
    arg0.execSQL("CREATE TABLE CONSUMER(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + 
            "CONSUMER_ID INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            "METER_NO INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            "PREV_READING INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            "CURR_READING INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            "IMAGE TEXT NOT NULL," +
            "STATUS INTEGER NOT NULL)");
    arg0.execSQL("CREATE TABLE CONSUMER_XML(CONSUMER_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," +
            "METER_NO INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            "PREV_READING INTEGER NOT NULL)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    arg0.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST LOGIN");
    arg0.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST CONSUMER");
    arg0.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST CONSUMER_XML");
    onCreate(arg0);
}

public void addConsumer(String consumerid,String meter,String pr)
{
    db=getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("CONSUMER_ID", consumerid);
    cv.put("METER_NO", meter);
    cv.put("PREV_READING", pr);
    db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE2, null, cv);
}
public boolean count()
{
    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT CONSUMER_ID FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE2,null);
    if (c.getCount()>0)
          return true;
          return false;
}


public ArrayList<String> get_consumer_id()
{
    ArrayList<String>names1=new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("Select CONSUMER_ID from " + DATABASE_TABLE2, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    do
    {
        String s1=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("CONSUMER_ID"));
        names1.add(s1);
    }while(c.moveToNext());
    return names1;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your logcat clearly says that you are getting Index out of bounds exception by this.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:     Invalid index 1, size is 0
at com.dod.test.List_of_Consumer$1.onItemClick(List_of_Consumer.java:130)
```

What's your line number 130 in your code? If you could edit your question with more specific part of code, then there would be chances of having my answer edited according to that.

Comment: Looking at `onItemClick()`, I would wager it's: `String st=a.get(arg2);`

Comment: its commented part of my code on click event on back button u can see in my given code.

Comment: @appu m getting error on line as sam specified and i i got that its giving error as arrayoutofbound but why on 2nd time when i came on that activity. one very first time its working fine. that time its passing value...?

Comment: @YograjShinde Not sure but your list populated with the cid data,you may need to get the data from it.. i.e String st=cid.get(args), have you tried this

Comment: @YograjShinde Better debug your code. The best way to check is to log your arraylist item before it is actually used.

Comment: @Pragnani thank you. but it will works only if i have already data in my table. not when am parsing data and store in db first time. sry am new to android

Comment: @YograjShinde so you need pass your a array as list object to your adapter, because you are using two differnet lists one for populating listview and one for inserting data to the listview. So you either need to insert data to cid array before displaying list or you need to pass a array list

Comment: can i make both function on same array i.e cid...?

Comment: thanx all of u i got my error and solution thank u ver much...!